# Stop text editors from destroying whitespace in python files

Tags: python, whitespace, text-editor

I have this really irritating problem that I do not quite understand in which my python files are ruined (appear ruined??) when I open them in one text editor or another.  Spaces disappear and with them the control blocks.  Obviously this has something to do with how the whitespace is saved but I don't fully understand it or know how to control it.

I edit the files on up to three computers in multiple editors, mostly kate, nano and vim. I thought that I had them all set to tab=4 spaces with autoindent for *.py but apparently it's not working like that.

What do I need to do to insure my files behave consistently across text editors?  Some explanation of what the problem is together with specific advice for the above editors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know how to control it, why do you believe that you've set up all of the editors to handle tabs as spaces the same? What did you do to make them do that?  You need to figure out where the spaces are getting clobbered and investigate the settings of the specific editor that's doing it.

Comment: Why use multiple editors?  Learn one well.

Comment: This is at least 3 questions in one (each of the listed editors, plus the fuzzy "mostly" indicating that there are others out there).  If you want answers you should post individual questions for each editor and include your config.

Comment: @wooble Kate has a setting called `Indent using` which is set to `Spaces` and not `Tabulators` or `Tabulators and Spaces`.  I thought that would work, apparently it doesn't.
@WilliamPursell , sometimes I need to edit from a remote shell, otherwise I prefer kate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spaces, not tabs. Spaces are always interpreted as the same width, unlike tabs. PEP 8 (the python styleguide) [recommends spaces over tabs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), as does the [Google Python styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Indentation).

Thus, if you consistently use spaces only, your code will always be indented properly.

You can check your python files for inconsistent tab usage by running the code with the `-tt` switch:

```
python -tt yourscript.py
```

Once you've cleaned up inconsistencies, use the Unix [`expand` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) to replace tabs with spaces:

```
expand -t 4 yourscript.y
```

where `-t 4` instructs `expand` to replace tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: This is useful information, but doesn't answer any of the actual questions asked.

Comment: @JimStewart: I'm trying to help the OP solve the problem at hand, by showing him how that avoiding tabs will solve these problems. Why help the OP bang their head against the doorpost when you can show them the doorway instead? Besides, without more detailed information about the settings for the editors *or* the contents of the files, there isn't anything *else* we can do for the OP at the moment.

Comment: @JimStewart: So how is this information not useful or not helpful to the OP? Is it factually wrong? If you have a better answer, please do post it!

Comment: It's not factually wrong, it's just not an answer to the question.  I would have put this into a comment on the question itself as an aside on how to fix existing broken files.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that one or more of your editors is mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Even if you have every editor set to display a tab as 4 spaces, Python will treat indentation of 2 tab characters differently from indentation of 1 tab and 4 spaces, although they will look identical in your editors. You need to configure your editors to insert a fixed number of spaces instead of a tab character. That, however, is off topic for Stack Overflow; you'll need to ask for your specific editors at, e.g., superuser.com.

Comment: Questions about tools, including editors, used in programming are on-topic here, actually.